# Поиск координаты пикселя пересечения линий разных цветов на картинке

Tags: python, opencv, pillow

необходимо найти точку пересечения линий разных цветов на картинке и обвести область пересечения. Есть идея реализовать обычным цикличным методом сравнения цветов пикселей. Я слышал про библиотеку openCv, но никогда не работал с ней. Посмотрел про методы определения контуров и поиском объектов разных цветов, но про поиск пересечений ничего не нашёл. Хотел бы услышать мнение людей, которые уже сталкивались с таким или которые могут подсказать идею, спасибо[image: Пример картинки для поиска пересечения]

Answer (score 0):

Вариант первый:

1. Размытие по Гауссу.
2. "Вычитание" фиолетового цвета (абсолютная разница)
3. Бинаризация по порогу.

Вариант второй:

1. Бинаризация по порогу.
2. Скелетонизация
3. Размытие по Гауссу с небольшим ядром.
4. Бинаризация по порогу.